# What are the good steps to cook a curry in the cooking mini game?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

While cooking in the new mini game of Sword and Shield, you have three different steps to accomplish:

- Working on the fire
- Mixing the curry
- "Putting your heart into it"

There is no real indicator in the game to explain you when you're doing one of those steps correctly. For instance, are you supposed to wave your fan like crazy in the first phase or to do it moderately? And when are you supposed to send the yellow ball in the curry in the last phase?

Comment: I have the same question for the first two points, but for "Putting your heart into it" it seems to be when the indicator overlaps the smaller, green, inner circle. Also, when stirring too fast, curry may splash over and the controller will vibrate. That might also be an indicator of stirring to fast, though I have no evidence to support either claim.

Comment: I think that change which pokemon will like it, for example fanning not quickly but mixing it very quickly, made it good for Smogo. The same recipe with fanning very quickly but mixing it slowly made it good for Milcery. Do not know if that does it for every recipe tho

Comment: Is there a rythm for the fanning the flames? I usually mash but sometimes, when I try a little slower it seems to have a better result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems “the code has been cracked” by someone [at Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/pokemon-sword-shield-guide/2019/11/20/20972429/how-to-make-the-best-curry-copperajah-charizard)!

I’ve been attempting to confirm these steps, and so far it seems at least somewhat effective.

**Use rare berries**

> We recommend using at least seven berries to yield a high-ranking curry, but less may work too, depending on your berry rarity.

**Fan the flames hard, without burning the curry**

> The goal here is to get to the biggest size flame, as quickly as possible, without burning it. If you go one level above the right flame size, the curry will burn. You’ll be able to tell you’re doing well because **not only will the pot sparkle, but Pokémon will come and celebrate** your curry.

**Don't spill while stirring**

> Just go for a nice steady stir, without spilling. You can tell **you’re doing good work if you see sparkles above the pot**. The spills will also make your controller vibrate pretty hard...

**Aim for the light green circle**

> ...aim for the lighter green circle on the inside.

**Cook with other players or NPCs**

> Making curry with other people or NPCs has yielded Charizard-rank more often, simply because it’s easier to do everything we listed above with more people.

Comment: It might be worth emphasising about the Sparkles in the first two stages (the *"indicator in the game to explain you when you're doing one of those steps correctly"*).  Cooking with others seem to have a **big** impact, as even a burned & spilled one-berry curry made with 2 inept NPCs seems to always be Milcery (Bronze/rank 3) class, but on my own with more/better berries and all sparkles is always Wobbuffet (rank 4) class (tested early game/2 gym badges)

Comment: @Chronocidal thank you, I've added an emphasis to the relevant parts.