# Pokemon Berry Combos for Charizard Class Curry Dex

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

If I follow the steps here when cooking: [What are the good steps to cook a curry in the cooking mini game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360296/what-are-the-good-steps-to-cook-a-curry-in-the-cooking-mini-game/360466#360466)

Will these combos guarantee charizard class curry even with common main ingredients?

- Balanced: 2 Liechi, 2 Ganlon, 2 Salac, 2 Petaya, 2 Apicot
- Spicy: 6 Liechi, 1 Cheri
- Sweet: 6 Liechi, 1 Pecha
- Dry: 6 Ganlon, 1 Chesto
- Bitter: 6 Ganlon, 1 Rawst
- Sour: 6 Salac, 1 Aspear